# how to recover an unsaved edited pdf on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: data-recovery

i was editing a document viewer PDF file *as in adding comments and stuff*    and i accidentally forgot to save my edits, so is there any possible way for me to recover those edits?

Comment: That will depend on the software being used for the edit (which you did not mention), but most likely you will not be able to recover.

Comment: i use the document viewer(ubuntu's default PDF viewer)

Answer (score 2):

## Not really

Files that are being edited by a program are loaded in RAM. They are generally never written to disk until you save, so there is no data to recover from the disk.

In some instances some text strings can be extracted from RAM, but this requires obtaining a RAM dump from the running system. This is a difficult process that should be performed by trained digital forensics experts. Also, if you turned off your computer in the meantime then it will be completely worthless.